Flutter serial port reads wrong bytes
I've tried to write an app in flutter to read a serial port connected to an Arduino Mega or ESP32 using flutter_libserialport. The problem is when I connect the device and open the port in flutter, the received characters are not convertible to string. But if I open the port using Arduino IDE or my Java app, it works smoothly. And then I close those apps and run my flutter apps again, and it works great and can easily convert all bytes. I used these work around: https://github.com/jpnurmi/libserialport.dart/issues/24, but none of them are working.
this is my code:
    final port = SerialPort("COM3");
    port.config = SerialPortConfig();
    port.config.baudRate = 115200;
    if (!port.openReadWrite()) {
      print(SerialPort.lastError);

    }else{

       final reader = SerialPortReader(port);
       reader.stream.listen((data) {
       print('received: ' + utf8.decode(data));
       });
    }


tried: reader.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(print); ?

@pskink yes, and It gave me an error: The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'.

it didnt give error, but no difference in the behavior of the pp. The problem is if I connect to serial using another app and close the port, then start my flutter app, it works smoothly without any problem in handling the bytes.

and what is the exact error / top frames from stack trace?

btw the same result if you use: reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().transform(Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true)).listen(print); ?

@pskink it shows some messed up characters. My problem is exactly like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/r3cf23/issues_in_communicating_via_serialport_in_flutter/. but their solution doesnt work for me.
